# Default namespace and prefix in Proxy Service WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am developing a proxy service in WSO2 ESB.

With this configuration, I retrieve the xml web service response. The response uses a default namespace as shown:

```
<enrich>
<source type="body" clone="true" />
<target type="property" property="soapXmlResponseReadCahceDataService" />
</enrich>
```

This is the xml response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body>
<cacheServices **xmlns="http://cache.services"**>
<cacheService>
   <id>1</id>
   <xmlrequesthash>b1e97b67-1226-4b1d-9081-b2a140690efd</xmlrequesthash>
   <xmlrequestpayload>c</xmlrequestpayload>
   <xmlresponsepayload>d</xmlresponsepayload>
   <quantity>1</quantity>
   </cacheService>
</cacheServices>
</soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
```

thereafter I need get the element **quantity**:

```
<property xmlns="http://cache.services" name="count" expression="//cacheServices/cacheService/quantity" />
```

WSO2 ESB does not allow you to place a namespace without a prefix, and I can not obtain this value. I can do to obtain this value, since the xml response has no namespace prefix?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this xpath in property mediator ?

```
 <property name="count" expression="//*[name()='cacheServices']/*[name()='cacheService']/*[name()='quantity']" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Alternatively you can use this by adding any namespace prefix since you are using default namespace.

```
 <property xmlns:ns1="http://cache.services" name="count" expression="//ns1:cacheServices/ns1:cacheService/ns1:quantity" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Shelan, with this expression I could obtain this value. In wso2 Data Services is possible change default namespace with a prefix (xml soap response) to simplify the xpath expression?

Comment: No in Data services you cannot specify the prefix. I have improved the answer you can define it simplified as it is. (i learnt that while finding an answer to your question.) Thanks